# Exception Handiling in Independent functions, without stoping the C# Console Application

Tags: c#, console, console-application, console.log

I am working on C# console application.

Want to impliment "Exception Handling".

Below are the code of ConsoleApp.

```
    static public void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                ONE_IndependentProcess(i);
            }
            TWO_IndependentProcess();
            THR_IndependentProcess();
        }
        catch (System.TimeoutException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("System.TimeoutException");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("System.Exception");
        }
        finally
        {
            Console.WriteLine("End.");
        }
    }
```

If an error occurs in TWO_IndependentProcess... application stops, without executing the THR_IndependentProcess

#1. In this case i want THR_IndependentProcess to be execute, and write a Exception Error Information of TWO_IndependentProcess in the Console.

If an error occurs in the ONE_IndependentProcess(3) (in 3rd iteration) application stops, without executing the: remaining iteration(4 to 9), TWO_IndependentProcess & THR_IndependentProcess

#2. In this case also i want the app to execute all, and just write a Exception Error Information of ONE_IndependentProcess(3) in the Console.

Note: I have four Catch block with Detail Exception Information and i want to apply all these four catch block in all three IndependentProcess function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you keep just one copy of your error handling logic and make use of lambda functions to wrap the calls with it:

```
static private void WithCatch(Action f)
{
    try
    {
        f();
    }
    catch (System.TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("System.TimeoutException");
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("System.Exception");
    }
}
static public void Main(string[] args)
{
    WithCatch(() => {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
           ONE_IndependentProcess(i);
    });
    // You could also do this inside the for loop for each one if you want
    // to attempt all 10 even if one fails:
    //for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    //    WithCatch(() => {ONE_IndependentProcess(i);});

    WithCatch(() => {TWO_IndependentProcess();});
    WithCatch(() => {THR_IndependentProcess();});
}
```

Comment: I am looking at this answer now for the 4th time, such a brilliant one.

Comment: Seems good... I will implement it and let you know by "mark as answer"... Thanks

Comment: @sgk, Thanks. I use this pattern quite a bit in place of copying code (and not just for error handling).

Answer (score 0):

You need to move each independent process into a separate try/catch block.

e.g.

```
static public void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            ONE_IndependentProcess(i);
        }
    }
    catch (System.TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("System.TimeoutException");
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("System.Exception");
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("End.");
    }

    try
    {
        TWO_IndependentProcess();
    }
    catch (System.TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("System.TimeoutException");
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("System.Exception");
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("End.");
    }

    try
    {
        THR_IndependentProcess();
    }
    catch (System.TimeoutException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("System.TimeoutException");
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("System.Exception");
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.WriteLine("End.");
    }

}
```

Comment: The for loop should be outside the try catch, as the OP wants the loop to continue if a given iteration throws.  Also you could warp the whole thing in Try/Finally rather than having many Finally blocks as this will write out many "End."

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use catch blocks within independent functions/process and deal with the exception within that catch block. This way you can allow program execution to continue without terminating.

try using generic functions to record exceptions - that way you can reuse this function within different catch blocks.